# How can I determine the character of alternating series?

Tags: calculus

Is the series  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}(\frac{n+1}{2n})$ convergent or divergent? It does not satisfy the required condition of alternating series. So, is there another way to determine its character.

Comment: The terms do not have limit $0$: automatic divergence.

Answer (score 2):

**If** the series $\sum_1^\infty b_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=0$. (The converse does not hold.)

In our case, the limit of the terms is not $0$ (it does not even exist). So the series does not converge.